# Return NULL when a COUNT is less than 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like my stored proc to return a NULL in a column if the COUNT result is less than one, otherwise return the COUNT value. It is kind of a reverse ISNULL???

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Requests WHERE RequestDB = RequestDatabase.RequestDB 
    AND RequestStatus < 3) AS OpenRequests
FROM RequestDatabase
```

I was thinking maybe use a CASE WHEN, but I got an error stating my CASE cannot be null.

Comment: What's wrong with returning a count of zero?

Comment: nothing, in this situation I have better handling in the client application for nulls than casting and testing for zero

Comment: You should not use `NULL` to represent the output of count unless the count operation fails. I think you should refactor the way you are interpreting the value you're trying to write as `NULL`.

Comment: I believe you would need to cast anyway. Otherwise, how do you get non-zero values? So the only extra step is your `IF` and this is unavoidable in any case.

Comment: I agree with all of your points, and that would be my normal route, however I was hoping in this simple implementation that I could keep the data formatting in SQL. Rows that have "Open Requests" will display its count of open requests, otherwise shows only its database name. Thank you for all the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of NULLIF() function.

```
SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0)
FROM TableName
```

Your count will be 0 or greater than Zero, since you want anything that is less than one to be null this leaves you with only value Zero and you can write you query like this...

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(*),0) FROM Requests WHERE RequestDB = RequestDatabase.RequestDB 
    AND RequestStatus < 3) AS OpenRequests
FROM RequestDatabase
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of achieving this would be to use `SUM(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`

As `SUM(1)` will return `NULL` anyway if run on an empty resultset. Or the number of rows otherwise.

Comment: `SELECT *, 
(SELECT SUM(1) FROM Requests WHERE RequestDB = RequestDatabase.RequestDB 
    AND RequestStatus < 3) AS OpenRequests
FROM RequestDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me and returns `NULL` as desired.

```
DECLARE @test INT
SET @test = 0

SELECT (CASE WHEN @test < 1 THEN NULL ELSE @test END) --NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a version of SQL Server that supports it, the `IIF` (immediate if) function will do it. Otherwise, you'll have to do something with `CASE`, which is also doable.

```
SELECT *, 
       (SELECT IIF(COUNT(*) == 0, NULL, COUNT(*)) FROM Requests WHERE RequestDB = RequestDatabase.RequestDB AND RequestStatus < 3) AS OpenRequests
FROM RequestDatabase
```

But as commenters have said, this doesn't sound like best practice. Convert to null on your client if need be, but don't do it in T-SQL.

Comment: thanks, nice tip, but not of the appropriate version